# Powershell Invoke-RestMethod To Return JSON

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-2.0, psobject

I am using PowerShell to run a php script on a daily basis. I can't seem to get the `json` return back from `Invoke-RestMethod`. How can that be accomplished?

Here is the code I am using:

```
$limit = 200;
for ($i=1; $i -le $limit; $i++)
{                          
    Write-Host $i started of $limit
    $Site = "http://example.com/updates"
    $Info = Measure-Command{
        $data = @{call_type = 'powershell'}
        $resp = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -URI $Site -Body $data -TimeoutSec 500).results       
    }
    Write-Host resp - On $resp.date, $resp.num were downloaded 
    Write-Host $i took $Info.TotalSeconds s 
    Write-Host ---------------------------------------
}
```

The PHP script is passing back a json string like:

```
{date: '2014-09-30', num: 127569}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `.results`. `Invoke-RestMethod` converts JSON into a `[PSObject]` automatically.

If you want to get the raw JSON then use `Invoke-WebRequest`, but since you reference `$resp.date` and `$resp.num` it seems like you wanted it to do the conversion for you after all.